# Special characters in angularJs function parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call function with parameter that contains html tags and special characters:

$scope.translate is JSON like {"phrase": "phrase1"}

JS:

```
   $scope.t = function(phrase) {
    if ($scope.translate[phrase]) {
      return $scope.translate[phrase];
    } else {
      return phrase;
    }
   }
```

HTML:

```
<label class="sub-label" for="" >{{t("Fields required are marked with <span> * </ span>")}}</label>
```

When there are special characters - the function is not processed, but instead shows the code.
I guess that this is the result of processing variables in angularJS.
How do I properly solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have this hardcoded in your HTML template, you will need to put entities for special characters. This means using

```
<label class="sub-label" for="" >{{t("Fields required are marked with &lt;span&gt; * &lt;/ span&gt;")}}</label>
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, it helps to escape error, but I want to save html enitities in string param that I pass to function.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to include ngSanitize package in your app, and then use [ngBindHtml directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: But I dont want to clean string, I want to pass it to function "as is". I need to save html structure in the strings.